# Кэширование картинок с сервера в памяти приложения

Tags: java, android

Можно ли реализовать такую схему? Человек впервые заходит в приложение, переходит на фрагмент с recycler view и в этом момент картинки загружаются с сервера, но после этого они должны остаться в памяти приложения и быть доступными даже без интернета до тех пор, пока они не будут заменены на сервере (актуальность проверяется во время подключения с интернетом) и новые картинки не будут загружены.Кто пытался уже сделать нечто подобное? Как их сохранить в кэше приложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого как минимум есть две библиотеки [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) и [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Вы можете дополнительно указать изображение или спиннер пока картинка грузится. Так же показывать дефолтную картинку, если изображение не было загружено.
Принцип такой, появляется интернет, если картинки нету, то он начнет загружать. При следующем запуске, он берет из кэша.

Пример работы Picasso

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Пример работы Glide

```
 Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView);
```

Чем они отличаются, есть несколько интересных статей. Например [Glide vs Picasso](https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d)

Answer (score 2):

Если кому то интересно я ответил по этой тему в этом вопросе:

[Как показать ProgressBar во время загрузки данных для recycler-view?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933802/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-progressbar-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-recycler-view)